# I would like some help wth an SQL query to link posts with categories

Tags: database, mysql

I am extracting data from my Wordpress database to analyse site structure. Works pretty good so far but I would like to include the posts main category in the table to enable further analysis. This is my current query:

```
SELECT post_name, post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish'
```

How can I enhance this query to include the main category in the result? I am pretty simple when it comes to SQL queries and would love to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the term tables with the posts table, something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    p.post_name,
    p.post_content,
    t.name
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON ( tr.object_id = p.ID )
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON ( tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id )
JOIN wp_terms t ON ( t.term_id = tt.term_id )
WHERE
    p.post_type='post'
AND
    p.post_status='publish'
AND
    tt.taxonomy = 'category'
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for writing this. The only thing I had to change was the wp prefix for table names as I use the multi-network plugin.